# Child viewcontroller view not expanding on rotation

Tags: ios

I have a container view controller set as my root view controller.  In this I have 2 child view controller stacked one on top of the other (so only the top most view is visible).  When I rotate from portrait to landscape, my bottom view controllers view get's rotated and expanded correctly (filling the screen) but my top view controllers view doesn't get expanded (so I can see the bottom view controller on the right of the top view controller).

I was assuming that since both of these were added as children of the container that they'd both rotate and expand appropriately but it doesn't appear to be working that way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you could check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth and UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight.  The way they work is, if the parent view changes size, the child view (with appropriate mask) will adjust width and height proportionally.  If you want a child view controller's view to fill the size of the parent at all times, then you do something like this:

```
childVC.view.frame = parentVC.bounds;
childVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;
```